# Move/resize Mac partition?

Tags: partition

I have 2 partitions (2.6gb, and 150gb) on one of my (3gb) drives.
It had 3, but I removed one that wasn't used.

Disk Utility should allow me to expand the 'lower' (150gb) partition into the free space - but not the 'top (2.6gb) partition.

Is there a way, using terminal or an app, that I can expand that 'top' (2.6gb) partition into the free space?